# Qt Assistant do not work, give error:"The page could not be found..."

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I want to develop GUI with PyQt5. Eric6 was choosed because it works well with Qt designer.Both PyQt5 and Eric6 have been installed suceessfully and they can work,I have build a project for trial. As a beginner,I need to use Qt assistant to learn,but Qt assistant do not work, give error:"The page could not be found...".The searching in index do not work also.

[image: I search "edit",but do not work]

I try to uninstall and install again and again,I even try different version  PyQt,but error remains.Then I installed Qt5,which contains Qt Creator,of which the Qt assistant works well.

[image: the Qt assistant of Qt5 works well]

So there are two Qt assistant on my computer now,I am confused why the PyQt5 one do not work,how can I solve the problem?
The versions are as follows:

- windows 10,64bit
- PyQt5:PyQt5-5.6-gpl-Py3.5-Qt5.6.0-x32-2(which contains Qt Assitant but does not work)
- Eric6:eric6-17.01,eric6-i18n-zh_CN-17.01
- Python(I have two version installed):

  Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit  (Intel)] on win32
  Python 2.7.12  (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
- Qt：qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.6.2(which contains Qt Assitant but  works well)

It seemed that Eric6 do not need Qt5,I am thinking if it is possible to use
Qt5's Qt designer to replace PyQt5's own one.BTW,can anybody gives me some suggestions on learning PyQt5?Thanks

Comment: Is `Qt5-doc` installed?

Comment: Thanks,I installed Qt5,which should have already contained  Qt5-doc. So I think there is no need to install Qt5-doc,and the Qt Assistan works well.Do you mean that I need to install Qt5-doc for PyQt5,if it is,how?

Comment: I'm sure the packaging is much different between our platforms, but under Arch Linux qt5-doc is a separate package that is listed as an optional dependency for qt5-tools, which contains qt-assistant, qt-designer, etc. I once was having exactly the same problem as you've shown.  I can't remember just what fixed it, but I did install qt5-doc at some point.  If qt5-doc is available as a separate package for your OS it's worth trying.